# How to decide the number of cepstral coefficients?

Tags: speech-recognition, sound, cepstral-analysis

For audio classification we are using cepstral coefficients, but how should I decide the number of coefficients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [CMUSphinx FAQ](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhat_speech_feature_type_does_cmusphinx_use_and_what_do_they_represent):

> There are various types of MFCC which differ by number of parameters,
>   but not really different for accuracy (it might be a few percent worse
>   or better).
>
> The interpretation of MFCC (Roughtly introduced Alan V. Oppenheim and
>   Ronald W. Schafer. From Frequency to Quefrency: A History of the
>   Cepstrum. IEEE SIGNAL PROCESSING MAGAZINE) is not applicable as such,
>   and the use of 12 or 13 coefficients seem to be due to historical
>   reasons in many of the reported cases. The choice of the number of
>   MFCCs to include in an ASR system is largely empirical. To understand
>   why any specific number of cepstral coefficients is used, you could do
>   worse than look at very early (pre-HMM) papers. When using DTW using
>   Euclidean or even Mahalanobis distances, it quickly became apparent
>   that the very high cepstral coefficients were not helpful for
>   recognition, and to a lesser extent, neither were the very low ones.
>   The most common solution was to “lifter” the MFCCs - i.e. apply a
>   weighting function to them to emphasise the mid-range coefficients.
>   These liftering functions were “optimised” by a number of researchers,
>   but they almost always ended up being close to zero by the time you
>   got to the 12th coefficient.
>
> In practice, the optimal number of coefficients depends on the
>   quantity of training data, the details of the training algorithm (in
>   particular how well the PDFs can be modelled as the dimensionality of
>   the feature space increases), the number of Gaussian mixtures in the
>   HMMs, the speaker and background noise characteristics, and sometimes
>   the available computing resources.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I guess we will have to allocate some computing power for select an optimal number of coefficients too along with the frame length:-)

Comment: It should be noted that this answer is specific to "speech" recognition. For speaker recognition, higher cepstral coefficients are more important.

Comment: I need to binary classify non-human audio signals, with little change over time, does that indicate that I fewer or more coefficients?

Comment: Then you probably don't need mel coefficients at all. Mel is specifically targetted to human speech. It all depends on the nature of the signals.

Comment: @Nikolay Yes their is no real argument for using the Mel-scale but i guess Cepstral coefficients still can be used as feature for my classifier.